# How to populate a dropdown on clicking a HTML button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to populate a dropdown on clicking a HTML button using javascript or jQuery.Please suggest me some links if having.
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: What did you tried? How do you get data?

Comment: generate and append the option html to the dropdown while clicking the button.

Comment: @Shawn Chin so are questions of this kind...

Comment: Still haven't found valid Answer. All are making their points.Links referred here points to ASP Dropdownlist controls rather than valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

First bind a handler for click event on the button

```
("#myBtnId").click(function (){
    populateDropDown();
});
```

Then make a function that populate the Dropdown

```
function populateDropdown(){
    var $myDD = $("#myDropDownId");
    $myDD.append("<option value='value'>Text</option>");   
}
```

Notice if you have a list of items you just change the code for iterate over the list and put values and text for the options dinamically.

```
function populateDropdown(listOfItems){
    var $myDD = $("#myDropDownId");
    for (var i = 0; i<listOfItems.lenght; i++){
       $myDD.append("<option value='"+ listOfItems[i].value +"'>"+listOfItems[i].text+"</option>");   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straightforward.

You just need to either have an onclick event or use event binding for the button to call a function which will populate the dropdown.

E.g. `<button type='button' onclick='Populate();'>Populate</button>`

And then your JavaScript function simply adds in the values:

```
function Populate() {

  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown_id_here");

  dropdown.options[0] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
  dropdown.options[1] = new Option('Text 2', 'Value2');

  // And so on, add as many options as required.
}
```

There are undoubtedly dozens of ways to achieve this functionality so other solutions may suit you better or be simpler.

Comment: Best answer, raw JavaScript is best solution in this case I think

Comment: @karaxuna Thanks, yeah I'll use jQuery if I'm already using it on a page, but no sense adding the overhead if it's not too necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `appendChild()` function of the select tag and keep adding your options. You can find the details at: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp

You can also do it in jQuery using the `append()` function: http://api.jquery.com/append/

You can have a look at the working code at: http://jsfiddle.net/shubhanshumishra/jHFZZ/

```
<input id="clickMe" value="clickme" type="button" />
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select Fields</option>
</select>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$i=0;
$("#clickMe").click(function(e){
    $i++;
    $("#dropdown").append("<option value='"+$i+"'>New Field</option>");
    });​
```